# Jquery Event Handler Functions

Tags: jquery

What is the difference between the following two pieces of code in terms of how the functions are handled?

```
$("#div").someEvent(function(){
    myFunction();
});


$("#div").someEvent(myFunction());
```

Comment: Did you actually mean `$("#div").someEvent( myFunction );`? You're now getting answers for the literal question and from people assuming there's a typo.

Comment: No, I meant what I typed.  Perhaps it is incorrect; I simply don't know jQuery enough to know that that was a "typo".  Though it begs the question, is what I typed technically possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is the first one calls `myFunction` when `someEvent` occurs, where as the second one calls the function `myFunction` first and try to register the value returned by it as the handler for `someEvent`. So in the second case `myFunction` is called when the line `$("#div").someEvent(myFunction());` is executed not when the event is triggered.

The right way is to do `$("#div").someEvent(myFunction);`, which will just the reference to `myFunction` as the event handler.

Answer (score 0):

#### regarding second example

In the second exaple you have given

```
$("#div").someEvent(myFunction());
```

the result of the function call is registered to execute on when the `someEvent` happens.
So when the event is registered the function call happens and its result is assigned there.

This approach can be used when `myFunction` is a function which returns a function when it is executed.

like

```
var myFunction = function () {

   return function(){
    myFunction();
   }

}
```

#### regarding first example

```
$("#div").someEvent(function(){
    myFunction();
});
```

you are registering an anonymous function and it will get executed  when the `someEvent` happens.

#### putting it together

To explain more

```
var myFunctionGenerator = function() {

   return function(){
      myFunction();
   }

}

//case1
$("#div").someEvent(function(){
    myFunction();
});

//case2
$("#div").someEvent(myFunctionGenerator());
```

In above sample both the code sample will be doing the same job. Only difference will be that the case2 will leave the reference to the function generator even after the code is executed.